# Uploaded plugin caused depreciation error WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I uploaded a plugin to customize my WooCommerce email headers but it caused a depreciation error in the email that have been sent. How can I fix these errors?

```
Notice: WC_Order::email_order_items_table is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wc_get_email_order_items instead. in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3853

Notice: WC_Order_Item_Meta::__construct is deprecated since version 3.1! Use WC_Order_Item_Product instead. in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3853
```

Comment: Disable the plugin if it is not kept up to date, else you could cause security/random errors that you encounter.

Comment: Just ask in author plugin pages support.

Comment: I already disabled and removed it  but it is still appears in every email except for **new order** email

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec  I just checked the forum and I am not the only one who has suffered from this plugin. But there is no answer were given to any of those topics.